# Cannot access Windows default shares using windows credentials

Tags: networking, windows

I am on (Windows 8 -ADMIN-PC)  (192.168.1.10) with DNS.
My other PC (windows 7 -USER-PC) (192.168.1.11) with same DNS

In my PC **(Windows 8 -ADMIN-PC)** I try to access **user-pc** by using windows explorer `\\192.168.1.11` with **username** and **password** then open `Users` Folder only. I can't access c$ or d$ shares.

Error given below.
[image: Error message screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

As the message in the screenshot states, the problem is that there is another connection to the same server from the same client, but with a different username. Windows does not support that. So, if you are supposed to have access to those default (`c$`, `d$`, ...) shares (which requires an administrator account on the remote computer), you have to connect with that account first, making sure you don't have an existing connection. From a command prompt you can list existing connections with the command:

```
net use
```

To disconnect one:

```
net use remote_path /d
```

(e.g., `net use \\192.168.1.11\User /d`). If you connect to one of the default shares with the Windows Explorer without being already connected to the remote machine with another account, Windows will directly ask for the username and password to use: if you enter those of an admin on the remote computer, you should be able to access the remote default share (provided of course that the remote admin account actually has a password, the access to admin accounts without passwords is blocked by default).